# Use AutoIncrement variable as Foreign Key - get Foreign Key contraint error

Tags: python, sql

I'd like to use an auto incrementing SQL variable as a Foreign Key. The code is written in Python/SQL (what is the correct way to say this?)
However, unless I put an actual number in, I get foreign key constraint errors.

I have read multiple posts about these errors and attempted to use the info...

Here are my two tables. Table1 is the top, Table2 is the bottom. ID is the foreign key.
I've put the number 1 into my code in order to stave off errors.

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | class |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | ONE  | TWO   |
|  2 | ONE  | TWO   |
|  3 | ONE  | TWO   |
|  4 | ONE  | TWO   |
+----+------+-------+

mysql> select * from table2;

+-----+------+-------+----+
| par | name | class | ID |
+-----+------+-------+----+
|   1 | SSS  | CAR   |  1 |
|   2 | SSS  | CAR   |  1 |
+-----+------+-------+----+
```

And here is the code

```
sql= """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
      `ID` integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `class` varchar(20) default NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
       )"""
cursor.execute(sql)

sql2 = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (
  `par` integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `class` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `ID` integer NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES table1 (ID),
  PRIMARY KEY (par)
  )"""          
cursor.execute(sql2)        

query = "INSERT INTO table1 (name, class) VALUES('ONE','TWO')"
cursor.execute(query)

query2 = "INSERT INTO table2 (name, class,ID) VALUES('SSS','CAR',1)"
cursor.execute(query2)
```

One more thing- putting a comma (Table2) in between FOREIGN KEY(ID) and REFERENCES gives error. ??

edit: I think my question is not clear. What I want is to make 'ID'
in table2

```
`ID` integer NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (ID)
```

reference

```
    `ID` integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
     PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
```

in table1

edit:
LAST_INSERT_ID() works for single row inserts.
[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) describes how to use for multiple rows.
Table2 does have multiple rows. 
    UPDATE table2 SET ID=LAST_INSERT_ID(ID+1);

The error message that I receive using this method is:
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`table2`, CONSTRAINT `table2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `table1` (`ID`))

Comment: So what is your question? Where are you getting errors?

Comment: in the line query2= ..., if I don't put a "1" there, I get errors. I want to reference the ID that autoincrements in table1. So I want to know what should I put in place of the 1 in order to make the foreign key work

Comment: And I want to know how you formatted my post too

Comment: @Tom there's an edit button under the question. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing) for more on [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing).

Answer (score 1):

In query 2, where you have the 1 you must insert one of the values of ID in table1. That is the meaning of FK, to throw an error if you don't insert a value existing in the referenced table.

Comment: yes, that is why I put a 1 there. But how do I make the 1 autoincrement, like the variable it is referencing?

Comment: As the other response answered, you can use LAST_INSERT_ID. But you shouldn't make it autoincrement. If you are always inserting 1 to 1, it means they are the same entity and should be in the same table. IF not you should have control what you insert, because you may want to insert a record in one of the tables and none in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1) MySQL provides [LAST_INERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).  For single row operations this will return the last generated autoincrement number.  For multi-row inserts you would have to keep track of the number of inserted rows since LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the first number generated for the operation.

Here is a one-to-one example:

```
query = "INSERT INTO table1 (name, class) VALUES('ONE','TWO')"
cursor.execute(query)

query2 = "INSERT INTO table2 (name, class,ID) VALUES('SSS','CAR',LAST_INSERT_ID())"
cursor.execute(query2)
```

Here's a one-to-many example:

```
#Insert the parent record
query = "INSERT INTO table1 (name, class) VALUES('ONE','TWO')"
cursor.execute(query)

#get the autoincrement id
cursor.execute('select LAST_INSERT_ID()')
parentId = cursor.fetchone()[0]

#Assuming you have several child records as a list of lists
childVals = [['SSS','CAR'],['FOO','BAR']]

#define the template child insert SQL using parameter substitution
# many dbapi modules use ? as the parameter placeholder, yours may use %s, etc.
query2 = "INSERT INTO table2 (name, class,ID) VALUES(?,?,?)"

#insert the child records with the parent id
for vals in childVals:
    #pass in the child record values with the parent id
    cursor.execute(query2, vals + [id])
```

Question 2) The REFERENCES is telling FOREIGN KEY where to look for related records, thus they are part of the same statement and must not be seperated by a comma.

Comment: I cannot see how to make multi-row inserts work. I get foreign key constraint errors

Comment: I added a one-to-many example for inserting multiple child records.  If you are adding multiple parent records I would suggest iterating through the parent insert statements to begin with.  Not the most efficient, but it is straight forward.

Comment: If you have an insert statement is generating multiple rows **at once** the cursor will usually report the number of affected rows, `cursor.rowcount`. You would use this rowcount to increment the LAST_INSERT_ID() response.

Comment: great explanation @tharen, thank you very much for taking the time to write this out.